# Turn Listing of Accounts and Properties into Grid Showing that Property Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large list of data to go through, looking to see if there is a property missing from an ID.  Rather than trying to look at a list of accounts and associated properties, I want to see if a property exists.

Current Data

```
ID1  |  ID2 | Properties
--------------------------
A    |   1  | Property1
A    |   1  | Property2
A    |   2  | Property1
A    |   2  | Property3
B    |   1  | Property1
B    |   1  | Property2
B    |   1  | Property3
B    |   2  | Property3
```

What I would like to end up with

```
ID1  | ID2  | Property1 | Property2 | Property 3
------------------------------------------------
A    |   1  |   Exist   |  Exist    |   NULL
A    |   2  |   Exist   |  NULL     |   Exist
B    |   1  |   Exist   |  Exist    |   Exist
B    |   2  |   NULL    |  NULL     |   Exist
```

Comment: How many `Properties` are there?

Comment: There could be upwards of 40 properties on an ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation

```
select id1, id2,
       max(case when properties = 'Property1' then 'exists' end) Property1,
       max(case when properties = 'Property2' then 'exists' end) Property2,
       max(case when properties = 'Property3' then 'exists' end) Property3
from your_table
group by id1, id2
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking, but we don't know how many `properties` exist